# FB.Canvas.getPageInfo().scrollTop property returns a wrong (old) value

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, scrolltop

Having same issue as [this guy](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108235):

> Hello mates
>
> Since a couple of hours, the FB.Canvas.getPageInfo().scrollTop
>   property returns a wrong (old) value when first accessed. When not
>   scrolling after the first access, it seems to return the correct value
>   when accessing FB.Canvas.getPageInfo().scrollTop again.
>
> Test case: https://apps.facebook.com/scrolltop-bug/
>
> Kilian Last edited by KilianSSL (2011-08-17 14:18:16)

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19884